# Почему в консоли при вводе нового инпута useReducer выдает новый объект?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно справиться со следующей проблемой? К примеру: у нас два инпута. Вводим в первый инпут имя: Иван, получаем в консоли `{name: "Иван", surname: ""}`, вводим во второй инпут фамилию: Иванов, получаем в консоли `{name: "", surname: "Иванов"}`. Почему не `{name: "Иван", surname: "Иванов"}`. Связано ли это с тем, что у нас каждый раз происходит перерендер компонента (очевидно, что происходит перерендер, ибо меняется состояние)?. Ниже приведен код. Заранее спасибо!

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
};

const ACTIONS = {
    CHANGE_INPUT: "CHANGE_INPUT",
}

export const officeReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ACTIONS.CHANGE_INPUT:
          return {
              ...state,
              [action.payload.name]:action.payload.value
          }
      default: {
          return state
      }
  }
}
```

```
import {useReducer, useState} from "react";
import {officeReducer, INITIAL_STATE} from "../../functions/officeReducer";

export const InputType = (props) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState()
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(officeReducer, INITIAL_STATE)

    function handleChange(e) {
      dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_INPUT", payload: {name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value}})
    }

    console.log(state) //так раз здесь мы и получаем разные объекты каждый раз

    return (
      <div className={styles.inputBox}>
        <input id={props.id} type={props.type} required={props.required} name={props.name} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <label htmlFor={props.id} className={text && styles.inputFilled}>{props.placeholder}</label>
      </div>
    )
}
```

```
const Office = () => {
return (
    <div className={styles.dataBox}>
      <div className={styles.dataInputs}>
        <InputType placeholder={'Surname'} name={'surname'} required={true} type={'text'}/>
        <InputType placeholder={'Name'} name={'name'} required={true} type={'text'}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

P.S. пробовал вынести useReducer в Office. Все работает, но у нас перерендеривается компонент Office, чего, конечно, хотелось бы избежать.